# What is the derivative of a matrix-valued composite function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-analysis, jordan-algebras

**Preliminaries: Jordan algebra**

In the sense of Jordan algebra, the following arrow matrix is often used to express the Jordan product $\circ$ which will be defined later: For a vector $a\in\Bbb R^m$,

$$
\mathrm{Arw}(a):=\left[\begin{array}{cc} a_1 & a_{-1}^\top \\ a_{-1} & a_1 I \end{array}\right],
$$

where $a_{-1}:=(a_2,\dots,a_m)^\top\in\Bbb R^{m-1}$.

For vectors $a,b\in\Bbb R^m$, the Jordan product $a\circ b$ of a and b is defined as

$$
a\circ b:=\left[\begin{array}{c} a^\top b \\ a_1b_{-1}+b_1a_{-1} \end{array}\right]\in\Bbb R^m.
$$

Here, the Jordan product can also be written as follows using arrow matrices:

$$
a\circ b=\mathrm{Arw}(a)b=\mathrm{Arw}(b)a.
$$

**Question**

I am struggling with the derivative of the vector-valued function with respect to $x\in\Bbb R^n$:

$$
f(x)\circ g(x),
$$

where $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$.

As I explained above, the question can be interpreted as the derivative of

$$
\mathrm{Arw}(f(x))g(x),
$$

or

$$
\mathrm{Arw}(g(x))f(x).
$$

However, I don't know the derivative of a composite matrix-valued function.
Thus I cannot apply the chain rule in the equation because of my lack knowledge about matrix analysis especially in the derivative of $\mathrm{Arw}(f(x))$.

Moreover, the question is more generalized as the derivative of

$$
X(f(x)),
$$

where $X:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb S^m$ is the matrix-valued function from $\Bbb R^m$ to a space of symmetric matrices $\Bbb S^m$.

It would be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: writing in components you have $(f(x)\circ g(x))_i = \sum_k ({\rm Arw}\,(f(x)))_{i,k}g(x)_k$ so one should have $d_x(f(x)\circ g(x))_i = \sum_k [d_x({\rm Arw}\,(f(x)))_{i,k}]g(x)_k+({\rm Arw}\,(f(x)))_{i,k}[d_xg(x)_k]$. What can you say about $d_x({\rm Arw}\,(f(x)))_{i,k}$?

Comment: @GiulioR Thank you for the comment. The remaining question is more explicit form of d_x Arw(f(x)) but I don't have any idea.

Comment: The point of my previous comment is that now $(\mathrm{Arw}\,f(x) )_{i,k}$ is just a scalar

Answer (score 1):

I will denote Jordan product by $\star$, since I'm too used to $\circ$ for composition.
Notice that your function $\def\Arr{\mathrm{Arr}} \def\R{\mathbb{R}} \Arr:\R^n \to M_n\R$ is linear, so
$$\Arr(a+h)=\Arr(a)+\Arr(h).$$
Hence, if $F(x)=f(x)\star g(x)=\Arr(f(x))g(x)$, you have, ignoring all terms where $h$ appears with order greater than $1$:
$$\begin{align}
F(x+h)
&= \Arr(f(x+h))g(x+h) \\
&= \Arr(f(x)+f'(x)(h))[g(x)+g'(x)(h)] \\
&= [\Arr(f(x))+\Arr(f'(x)(h)][g(x)+g'(x)(h)] \\
&= \Arr(f(x))g(x)+\Arr(f(x))g'(x)(h)+\Arr(f'(x)(h))g(x) \\
&= F(x)+f(x)\star g'(x)(h)+f'(x)(h) \star g(x).
\end{align}$$

Hence (again disregarding terms of higher order):
$$\begin{align}
F'(x)(h)
&=F(x+h)-F(x) \\
&=f(x)\star g'(x)(h)+f'(x)(h) \star g(x).
\end{align}$$

You might know $f'(x)$ as the Jacobian matrix $Jf(x)$. With this notation, you have
$$\begin{align}
F'(x)(h) &=f(x)\star (Jg(x)h) + (Jf(x)h) \star g(x).
\end{align}$$

---

Another, more direct way to obtain the above result is to note that $\star$ is linear in each entry, so
$$\begin{align}
(a+c)\star b &= a\star b + c\star b \\
a\star(b+c) &= a\star b + a\star c.
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
F(x+h)
&= f(x+h)\star g(x+h) \\
&= [f(x)+f'(x)(h)]\star[g(x)+g'(x)(h)] \\
&= F(x)+f(x)\star g'(x)(h)+f'(x)(h) \star g(x).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The key ideas: $\;1)$ the product rule for differentials, $\;2)$ the Jordan product commutes

$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\gx#1{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial x}}
h &= g\circ f \\ 
dh &= g\circ df &+\; dg\circ f  \qquad &\{1\}  \\ 
   &= g\circ df &+\; f\circ dg  \qquad &\{2\}  \\ 
\gx{h} &= g\circ \gx f &+\; f\circ \gx g \\\\
}$$

---

Interestingly, the arrow function can be expressed using standard matrix notation, leading to a purely matrix result
$$\eqalign{
F &= {\rm Arw}(f) \;\doteq\; fe^T + ef^T + \LR{e^Tf}\LR{I-2\,ee^T} \\
G &= {\rm Arw}(g) \,\;\doteq\; ge^T + eg^T + \LR{e^Tg}\LR{I-2\,ee^T} \\
\gx{h} &= G\LR{\gx f} + F\LR{\gx g} \\
}$$
where $e$ is the first euclidean basis vector.